# Unable to understand reason for Tie::File failure

Tags: perl

I have the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Tie::File;

tie my @last_id, 'Tie::File', 'last_id.txt' or die "Unable to open this file !$i";
print @last_id[0];

exit;
```

and a file named `last_id.txt` with something like this in it

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

When I run the program nothing gets output. I tried `$last_id[0]` but still nothing. :/

I have latest ActivePerl installed.

EDIT:

Now I get the `Unable to open this file` message, but the file exists in the same directory as the program source file.

Comment: what counts is from which dir you are running. try with absolute path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say, `@last_id[0]` is wrong and should be `$last_id[0]`. But this won't cause the problem you are seeing.

Note that the program won't look for `last_id.txt` in the same directory as the Perl source file unless it it also the current working directory.

You should first of all change the error variable used in the `tie` line to `$!` like this

```
tie my @last_id, 'Tie::File', 'last_id.txt'
    or die "Unable to open this file: $!";
```

as the variable `$i` contains nothing useful. This will tell you the *reason* for the failure of `tie`, which may be something other than *no such file or directory*.

You should also `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, as this will flag simple errors that are easy to overlook.

Finally, try fully-qualifying the filename by adding an absolute path to it. That will get around the problem of the program looking in the wrong directory by default.

---

**Update**

If the problem is that you have no write access to the file then you can fix it by opening it read-only.

You need the `Fcntl` module to define the `O_RDONLY` constant, so put this at the top of your program

```
use Fcntl 'O_RDONLY';
```

then the `tie` statement goes like this

```
tie my @last_id, 'Tie::File', 'last_id.txt', mode => O_RDONLY
    or die "Unable to open this file: $!";
```

Comment: it gave "Permission denied at" line 4.

Comment: Does that solve your problem? If you need only read access to the file but the `tie` is failing because you have no write permission then you can open it read-only. I have updated my answer to explain how this works.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer, I ended up putting it in absolute path. One more thing when I do `$absolute_path = 'C:\Users\...\Desktop\';` And then do `tie my @last_id, 'Tie::File', '$absolute_path\last_id.txt';` it doesn't open, and says unable to locate the file. Why would this happen? I am sure the file is there. When I type in the absolute path in the tie line, it works fine.

Comment: Because single quotes don't allow variables to be interpolated into the string and you are passing the string  `$absolute_path\last_id.txt` as a filename. Be careful with backslashes as they will eat the closing quote even in a single-quoted string. You may want to use forward slashes instead as Perl is happy with either on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The problem should go away if you use absolute paths

```
BEGIN {
    use File::Spec;
    use File::Basename qw' dirname ';
    use vars qw' $thisfile $thisdir ';
    $thisfile = File::Spec->rel2abs(__FILE__);
    $thisdir  = dirname($thisfile);
}
...
tie ... "$thisdir/last_id.txt"
```

Comment: im complete newbie in perl, where do I paste this?